# Hyper-V cluster: Unable to fail VM over to secondary host

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I am working on a Server 2012 Hyper-V Cluster. I am unable to fail my VMs from one node to the other using either LIVE or Quick migration.

A force shutdown of VMHost01 will force a migration to VMHost02. And once we are on VMHost02 we can migrate back to VMHost01, but once that is done we can't move the VMs back to VMHost02 without a force shutdown.

The following error pops up:

Event ID: 21502
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to establish a connection for a Virtual machine migration with host.... The connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (0X8007274C)

Here's what I noticed:

VMMS.exe is running on VMHost02 however it is not listening on Port 6600. Confirmed this after a reboot by running netstat -a. We have tried setting this service to a delayed start as suggested here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/roplatforms/archive/2012/10/16/shared-nothing-migration-fails-0x8007274c.aspx

I have checked Firewall rules and Anti-Virus exclusions, and they are correct. I have not run the cluster validation test yet, because I'll need to schedule a period of downtime to do so.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this particular issue?

Thanks,

Tho H. Le

Comment: Running a cluster validation is what you should do before you put the cluster into service. Get back to us when you've done that.

Comment: Cluster Validation Test was successful. There were no issues that were found. I am not seeing anything of interest in the event or cluster logs either. Again, I suspect the VM migration is failing because VMMS.EXE is not listening on port 6600.

Comment: Issue resolved: Some sort of GPO corruption occurred. We noticed that we could not launch gpedit.msc from VMHost02. Copied Group Policy Folder from VMHost01, and gpupdate /force.  Now VMMS.exe shows up and is listening on Port 6600, VM migrations work as well.